# Displaying date in MM/DD/YYYY format in Iphone Data picker

Tags: iphone, date, format, uidatepicker

In my Application i am using the UIdatePicker with fallowing code.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 216)];
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]; datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate; datePicker.date=[NSDate date]; datePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date]; [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In simulator UIDatepicker display as "MM/DD/YYYY" and in device "DD/MM/YYYY" format.

But i wan to display like "MM/DD/YYYY" in device.

Can any one help how to display it as "MM/DD/YYYY" format.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show it in the user's correct culture settings so they understand it properly.

Comment: In Apple Documentation they specified that           UIDatePickerModeDate
The date picker displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the locale setting. An example of this mode is [ November | 15 | 2007 ].                                  But In device it display as DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going into preferences->international, your device may configure in french language and french region format.